# Why does stack give wierd charcter encoding in error output on windows?

Tags: powershell, cmd, terminal, character-encoding, haskell-stack

I have a file `tmp.hs` with the following content:

```
{- stack
  script
  --resolver lts-10.3
-}
```

when I run `stack tmp.hs` I get the following output

```
?[;1mC:\Users\ludvig.hult\Source\adventofcode2016\Day1\tmp.hs:0:53: ?[;1m?[31merror:?[0m?[0m?[;1m?[0m?[0m?[;1m
    * Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)?[0m?[0m
```

running in CMD or PowerShell on my windows 10 machine. What kind of error is it? Character encoding? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ANSI color control codes.  You can suppress them with `--color never`.  It is likely due to the windows 10 fall creators update causing ANSI codes to no longer be parsed by default.  Instead, applications need to opt-in.

Please consider implementing a fix to this issue, likely in the ansi-terminal package https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3797 .  https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3785 may also be related.

Finally, a simple addition to the config would help with this - the ability to specify `color: never` - see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3778

Comment: thanks for the help. `stack --color never tmp.hs` works fine. I'm unfortunately far too inexperienced to implement a fix. :(